# Drupal 7 - How to get menu trail?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

i have a URL like: domain.com/content/travel in my drupal installation.

In D6 i used the following code to extract "travel" from the above mentioned trail:

```
$menuParent = menu_get_active_trail();
$path = $menuParent[1]['page_arguments'][0]->path;
$pathArray = explode('/', $path);
$menuParent = $pathArray[1];
$menuChild = trim($pathArray[3]);
```

This is not working in D7 anymore as menu_get_active_trail only delivers the "node/4" URL. How can i get the URL as mentioned above in D7?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the first comment on the menu_get_active_trail function page. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_active_trail/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[drupal_get_path_alias()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7)** function to get the path alias of active trail.

```
$menuActive = menu_get_active_trail();

// Get the path alias from active trail
$menuParent = drupal_get_path_alias($menuActive);

$path = $menuParent[1]['page_arguments'][0]->path;
$pathArray = explode('/', $path);
$menuParent = $pathArray[1];
$menuChild = trim($pathArray[3]);
```